# Employee shift scheduling optimization of multiple constraints

Tags: optimization, schedule, pyomo, or-tools

I am working on filling a daily schedule. During each day there are a number of tasks that have different shift lengths. For example, task_1 has three 8 hour shifts during a 24 hour period and task_2 has six 4 hour shifts during a 24 hour period. There is also a task which is only done during certain hours and consists of four 4 hour shifts during a 24 hour period.

On top of that, certain tasks require a group of employees with different experience levels. Employees can either be simple workers or team leaders. The group of employees is divided into three teams where each team consists of a number of leaders and workers. A constraint I have is that for tasks that require multiple employees , the employees need to be from the same team. For example, group_1 consists of 2 leaders and 3 workers [leader_1, leader_2, worker_1, worker_2, worker_3]. Task_1 requires a team leader and two employees and they need to be from the same group. I can schedule [leader_1, worker_1, worker_2] to the first shift but for the second shift I would only have 1 leader and 1 worker and would need to schedule employees from another group.

I am trying to schedule employees so that there is a maximum amount of time between shifts, i.e. they have as much downtime between shifts as possible. I'm hoping to find a way to automate the scheduling and have been looking at examples of or-tools and pyomo. Right now I don't even have an example code since I'm trying to understand if what I am trying to do is possible with the amount of variables and constraints I have.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure this is suited for a beginner. Looks to me not completely trivial.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wasn't sure either and since I am a beginner at this I didn't know if there was something I was missing that would make it doable. If there is no good answer should I delete the question?

Comment: Have you looked at the nurse scheduling examples at https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling? Some of your requirements may be more similar to the job shop scheduling problems https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/job_shop. If you google "job shop scheduling or-tools" and/or "nurse scheduling or-tools"  you'll get a lot of hits. Also see the Google OR-Tools forum at https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss